# Access violation when calling method of base class

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, access-violation

I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm probably missing something obvious. I'll admit that I don't fully understand how the object model works, but I hope I can learn something from this problem...

I have a simple wxWidgets application with a custom `wxFrame` class. It hooks up an event and inside that event handler, I want to set the title of the frame. When the event handler executes, however, the debugger shows that the address of the `SetTitle` function is `0x00000000` and I get an access violation exception.

```
class BrowserFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    BrowserFrame();

    void OnChangeTitle(AweChangeTitleEvent& evt);

private:
    AweWebView* m_webView;
};

BrowserFrame::BrowserFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxGetApp().Name) {
    m_webView = new AweWebView(this, wxID_ANY);
    m_webView->Connect(aweEVT_CHANGE_TITLE, AweChangeTitleEventHandler(BrowserFrame::OnChangeTitle));
    m_webView->WebView()->LoadURL(Awesomium::WebURL(Awesomium::WSLit("http://www.google.com")));
}

void BrowserFrame::OnChangeTitle(AweChangeTitleEvent& evt) {
    SetTitle(evt.GetTitle()); // SetTitle == 0x00000000, Access violation
}
```

My first thought was that the `BrowserFrame` was getting destructed somehow. That doesn't seem to be the case, though, because I can access it with `GetEventObject()`. This works just fine, for example:

```
void BrowserFrame::OnChangeTitle(AweChangeTitleEvent& evt) {
    static_cast<wxFrame*>(static_cast<wxWindow*>(evt.GetEventObject())->GetParent())->SetTitle(evt.GetTitle());
}
```

I can't think of anything I've written that would corrupt the v-table in any way, except for one instance where I do my own memory management on an image buffer. I've completely removed that portion and still get the access violation on `SetTitle`, so I don't think that's the source of the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check what `evt.GetTitle()` is returning?

Comment: Yes, it returns a valid `const wxString&`.

Comment: Did your window actually get created?  I'd guess that `SetTitle()` fails because there's no window.

Comment: @paddy: Yes, the window appears. Like I said, I can successfully execute `SetTitle` through a series of casts, but not directly.

Comment: Make clean? I've spent hours chasing down bugs that were caused by a class size changing and not all object files being recompiled.

Comment: How about this->SetTitle(...) or wxFrame::SetTitle(...)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I'll try to explain the solution as best I can.

If I understand the problem correctly, the event handler wasn't actually associated with an instance of `BrowserFrame`. I switched to the more modern `Bind<>()` method of connecting wxWidgets events and passed it the instance of `BrowserFrame`:

```
m_webView->Bind(aweEVT_CHANGE_TITLE, &BrowserFrame::OnChangeTitle, this);
```

I also had to update my custom event declarations to make them compatible with `Bind<>()`, but after that, `SetTitle()` is called and everything works great.